# reformat multiple variables with data.table in R

Tags: r, string, data.table, format, numeric

So I have a data table with thousands of variables. The data how ever is not very clean and so I ran the following bit of code to remove all the `-` and series of `-` from my `dt`.

```
dt <- as.data.table(lapply(dt, function(x) {
  gsub("-+", "", x)
}))
```

However, this code transforms all columns into `character` vectors. I would like to reformat all variables to their original `class` as well as any variables that where of `class` `character` into numeric if possible (so in the case of a variable being numeric but having at least one observation with a `-` somewhere, like `123-`.

This could be done through `fwrite()` and then `fread()` but I would like to avoid writing a temporary file only to re-importing it to the same session as this would take up storage and time.

---

### Example:

Say you have the following data:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(nums = 11:20,
                 char_nums = c(as.character(1:9), "10-"),
                 letters = letters[1:10])


# nums is of class integer, char_nums is of class character
str(dt)
```

The goal is to remove all series of `-`and have `nums` and `char_nums` be of `class` `integer` while retaining `class` `character` of `letters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use data.table, we can loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = '-+', replacement = "")]
dt1 <- type.convert(dt1, as.is = TRUE)

str(dt1)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ nums     : int  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#$ char_nums: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#$ lett     : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

---

Or use `as.numeric` after removing the `-`

```
dt1 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("-+", "", x)))]
```

But, this we will only do if we are sure that all the columns should normally of type `numeric`, but was changed due to `-`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, while your code does substitute all `-` all columns are still of class `character`at the end.

Comment: @cachdies it's because we didn't convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric` or simply use `type.convert`

Comment: The problem with simply adding `as.numeric()` is that the final column is filled with `NA` and all the information in it is lost.

Comment: @cachdies have you checked my update and answer.  I didn't simply added `as.numeric`.  It is after removing the `-` with `gsub` and assuming that your columns have only `-` as non-numeric value

Comment: @cachdies sorry, i didin't check your new example.  I was thinking that all the columns should be numeric.  My bad..  Use the first `type.convert` or else have to do an `if/else` in the second code

Comment: Your code is great, thank you. Do yo know how to extend it to bit64 integers from the `bit64` package?

Comment: @cachdies you may have to check `inherits`